# SwiftUI NavigationLink in LazyVGrid picking random index

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Every time a row is selected the system decides to forward a random index to the next view.

Please look at the following video for clarification:
[image]

Below is the code:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    @State var showDetail = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                        .background(NavigationLink(destination: TestDetail(index: index), isActive: $showDetail) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }).onTapGesture {
                            showDetail = true
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

struct TestDetail: View {
    var index: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(index)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You activate all links at once (because all of them depends on one state). Instead we need to use different `NavigationLink` constructor for such cases.

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct TestView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    @State var selectedItem: Int?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                        .background(NavigationLink(destination: TestDetail(index: index), tag: index, selection: $selectedItem) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }).onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = index
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard NavigationLink features, which automatically convert it into a button - you don't really need the .background and .onTapGesture.

```
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: TestDetail(index: index),
                        label: {
                            Text("\(index)")
                        })
                        .accentColor(.primary)
                }
```